# GWT: Catch native JSNI exception in Java code

Tags: java, javascript, exception, gwt, jsni

I have some logic in native method, which returns sth or null - they are both valid and meaningful states, and I want to throw an exception on method's failure. As it is native JSNI i am not sure how to do that.

So consider method:

```
public final native <T> T myNativeMethod() /*-{

    //..some code


    //in javascript you can throw anything, not only the exception object:
    throw "something"; 

}-*/;
```

but how to catch the thrown object?

```
void test() {
    try {
        myNativeMethod();
    }
    catch(Throwable e) { // what to catch here???
    }
}
```

Is there any special Gwt Exception Type wrapping "exception objects" thrown from JSNI?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

As to Daniel Kurka's answer (and my intuition ;)). My code could then look like that:

```
public final native <T> T myNativeMethod() throws JavaScriptException /*-{

    //..some code


    //in javascript you can throw anything it not just only exception object:
    throw "something"; 

    //or in another place of code
    throw "something else";

    //or:
    throw new (function WTF() {})();

}-*/;

void test() throws SomethingHappenedException, SomethingElseHappenedException, UnknownError {
    try {
        myNativeMethod();
    }
    catch(JavaScriptException e) { // what to catch here???

        final String name = e.getName(), description = e.toString(); 

        if(name.equalsIgnoreCase("string")) {

            if(description.equals("something")) {
                throw new SomethingHappenedException(); 
            }
            else if(description.equals("something else")) {
                throw new SomethingElseHappenedException(); 
            }
        }
        else if(name.equals("WTF")) {
            throw new UnknownError();
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 6):

From the gwt docs:

> An exception can be thrown during the execution of either normal Java
>   code or the JavaScript code within a JSNI method. When an exception
>   generated within a JSNI method propagates up the call stack and is
>   caught by a Java catch block, the thrown JavaScript exception is
>   wrapped as a JavaScriptException object at the time it is caught. This
>   wrapper object contains only the class name and description of the
>   JavaScript exception that occurred. The recommended practice is to
>   handle JavaScript exceptions in JavaScript code and Java exceptions in
>   Java code.

Here is the complete reference:
http://www.gwtproject.org/doc/latest/DevGuideCodingBasicsJSNI.html#exceptions

Comment: you mean com.google.gwt.core.client.JavaScriptException? to be sure :)

Comment: and just one mre question: the mentioned above "description" is retrieved wit getMessage() or toString()?

Comment: basically handle your JavaScript Exceptions in JavaScript and the Java Exceptions in Java. If you really need to throw something you can catch JavaScriptException in your Java code

Comment: i know there is a suggestion, in doc you put above, to handle js exceptions in jsni, but in this case i'd like to intentionally ignore it ;).